# Equivalent for T-SQL Table Value Constructor in Amazon Redshift?

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I'm coming from a T-SQL background, and I'm used to using table-value constructors for various purposes (e.g., a lookup to match a code to a human-readable string). Code usually looks like this...

```
SELECT a, b FROM (VALUES (1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8), (9, 10) ) AS MyTable(a, b);
```

I've tried running this code in Amazon RedShift to no avail. I've also dug through the docs looking for an equivalent, but I can't seem to find any. Is there an equivalent?

Comment: This *is* supported by Postgres (at least starting with 8.3). Seems redshift is based on a **really** old version of Postgres if it doesn't work there.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name According to the tag wiki, "Redshift is based on PostgreSQL 8.0." So yeah, pretty ancient by now, and presumably either missing a whole bunch of stuff or heavily diverged in feature set.

Answer (score 2):

Are you just using these as static values for testing or something? You can always do several UNION ALLs in a sub-query:

NOTE: I believe this should work fine, I am more accustomed to Oracle and SqlServer, but something similar should be available to you regardless of platform...

```
SELECT a, b
FROM 
(
   SELECT 1 AS a, 2 AS b
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 3 AS a, 4 AS b
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 5 AS a, 6 AS b
) MyTable;
```

Comment: Note that you don't need to repeat the "as a" and "as b" after the first line if you want brevity over symmetry.